# Using setAttribute of QDateTimeEdit in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I don't see my error in code. I can't save the current time into QDateTime field 'actualDate'. I get `None` by `setDateTime(QDateTime.currentDateTime())`.

```
mylayer = self.layer
actualDate = mylayer.fields().indexFromName('actualDate')

seg = mylayer.getSelectedFeatures()
for j in seg:
    self.dlg.actualDate.setDateTime(QDateTime.fromString(str(j.attributes()[actualDate])))

    # show dialog frame
    self.dlg.show()
    # Save
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
            
    # See if "Save" was pressed
    if result:
        # save process:
        mylayer.startEditing()
        now = QDateTime.currentDateTime() #get current DateTime
        self.dlg.actualDate.setDateTime(j.setAttribute(actualDate, self.dlg.actualDate.setDateTime(now))) 

        mylayer.updateFeature(j)
        mylayer.commitChanges()
        mylayer.removeSelection()
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution by myself:

```
datetimenow = j.setAttribute(actualDate, now)
    self.dlg.actualDate.setAttribute(datetimenow)
```

I do not have to `setDateTime()` when I defined already the `currentDateTime()`